# Font Preview Alert Dialog in Android

Tags: fonts

I want to create Font Preview inside alert dialog but i am not able to do that i can select fonts and all but i don't know how to generate fonts preview. If any one can help me in it i ll be grateful.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.lg_logo);
            builderSingle.setTitle("Select any font");

            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);


            arrayAdapter.add("Font1");
            arrayAdapter.add("Font2");
            arrayAdapter.add("Font3");
```

this way i am able to create and can select fonts to instead of Font1 and Font2 i want to show preview of them searched online but no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i am not wrong . you are trying to achieve something like following image .

[image: Result image]

so here is an answer of your question.here i am using radio button for single selection from lists.

in this i am using custom layout and shows all radio button with preview textview and inflate or use this layout in **alertdialog using setview() method**.

here is an xml layout code of this preview layout .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/luckiestguyregular"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:textSize="18dp" 
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/notomonoregular"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/merriweatherblack"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

here i am using radio button fontFamily attribute for showing preview of that particular radio button.

**`android:fontFamily="@font/merriweatherblack"`**

javacode file for viewing alertdialog with custom layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = Main2Activity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayoutforfont, null);
        Button bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this)
                        .setTitle("Choose fonts")
                        .setView(view1)
                        .setPositiveButton("set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                RadioGroup group = view1.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

                                Log.i("RadioButton", "ID " + group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                                if (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton) {
                                  editor=getSharedPreferences("FontShared",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                  editor.putString("fonts","luckiestguyregular.ttf").commit();
                                    recreate();

                                }
                                else if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== R.id.radioButton2){
                                    editor=getSharedPreferences("FontShared",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                    editor.putString("fonts","notomonoregular.ttf").commit();
                                    recreate();
                                }
                                else if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== R.id.radioButton3){
                                    editor=getSharedPreferences("FontShared",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                    editor.putString("fonts","merriweatherblack.ttf").commit();
                                    recreate();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();


            }
        });
```

For knowing which radio button was select i use below code.

first find radio group from that custompreviewfont layout using

`RadioGroup group = view1.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);`

and then **get currently checked radio button id using radioGroup views method called radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()**

finally i used if-else if statement to perform font applying operation

```
if  (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton) {
       //code of first radiobutton
}
else if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton2){
    //code of second radiobutton
}
```

..etc

hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help.